# kendo datasource.fetch scope

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource

im trying to create a function that simple returns a record from a remote source by the ID passed using Kendo's dataSource. however when i set the 'data' variable from within 'dataSource.fetch' the 'data' object still remains undefined. how do i set the 'data' object from within 'dataSource.fetch' so that i can return it.

```
 function getUserById(id){

  var data;

  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: "/data/users/",
        dataType: "jsonp"
      }
    },
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id_usr" }
    },
    serverFiltering: true,
    filter: { field: "id_usr", operator: "eq", value: id }
  });

  dataSource.fetch(function() {
    var dataItem = dataSource.get(id);
    if(dataItem){
      data = dataItem;
    }
  });

  return data;
}

user = getUserById("lrobinson");
name = user.fname+" "+user.lname;
```

Heres an example http://jsbin.com/IKazEHe/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `fetch` method is asynchronous. It will be done only when the "/data/users/" service finished loading. This is why `fetch` accepts a callback which is executed only when the response from the service has been received.

One way to deal with this is to make the ajax request synchronous by setting `async` to `false`:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: "/data/users/",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async: false /* make it synchronous (basically JAX ;))
      }
    },
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id_usr" }
    },
    serverFiltering: true,
    filter: { field: "id_usr", operator: "eq", value: id }
  });
```

Comment: i think i understand that but how do i set data = dataItem; in  dataSource.fetch so that my function getUserById() will return 'data'. thanks again

Comment: thanks again. really appreciate your help but i still cant get this to work loo. http://jsbin.com/IKazEHe/4/edit?js,output

Comment: Damn. That's because of JSONP which can't be made synchronous. You need to put your code in the fetch callback. There is no other way. Think of it as using $.ajax and its complete callback.

Comment: thanks. im quite new to this so im struggling with what your saying. could you possibly give me an example of how i can build a function to simply return/save the data into an array/object so that i can use it.

Comment: Simply put - you can't. You need to use the callback.

Comment: callback to assign the data. is that not what i did originally. i just couldn't pass the data to object/array outside the dataSource.fetch(). thats why i thought it was a scope issue

Comment: any more suggestions on how i can achieve this would be great guys

Comment: As I told you a few times before - you can't. Fetch is asynchronous. Your function will return before fetch callback is executed.

Comment: ok, well maybe another way to achieve it? I simply want a function that returns the data from the datasource as an array or object.

Comment: You must put the code which uses that value inside the fetch callback. As far as I know there is no way to return a value from a callback which is asynchronously executed.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, but even worse - those code is in calculated field of MVVM model so it can't be redesigned as far as I know to become asynchronous. To my luck I don't use JSONP